# Database design help

Tags: database-design, structure

```
CREATE TABLE cards (
  id INTEGER(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NULL',
  expire DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NULL',
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

CREATE TABLE `services` (
  `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NULL',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `shops` (
  `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NULL',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `card_transactions` (
  `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_card` INTEGER(1) NOT NULL,
  `funds` DOUBLE(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `timeCET` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `id_shops` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_services` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_payment_systems` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` ENUM('y','n') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `payment_systems` (
  `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `shop_sales` (
  `id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  id_shops INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  delivery_price DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  sales price DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id`)
);

Sorry i have an image but can't post it. So i post the code.
Is this a good db design? Would it be better if replace the last four columns from card_transactions table with for example reference_id and put them in new table called reference?

Comment: I hope you will be strongly encrypting this data....

Comment: Seems alright, one question: the 'user' column of the card_transactions table - what is it for? If it's a simple 'yes/no' selection then a BOOLEAN type would be better

Comment: Evaluating the quality of the data model without knowing the business rules and relationships that you are trying to model *must* make assumptions on the meaning of the names of your tables, fields and predicates. So it *must* be pretty subjective. In attempt to be a bit more helpful - when deciding to split a table look if your model is achieving the normal form that you are aiming for. The procedure is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess. Possible problems include

- No foreign key constraints.
- No unique constraints.
- No check constraints.
- Using floating point data types for
  money.
- No default timestamps for DATETIME
  columns.